# data table separated different button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i got data table, in data table row are two button, i wanna separated them, because one for delete, one for edit. I use js, to add what button. Picture bellow
[image]

Now then i press edit or delete i got the same.
my code js code

```
        'columnDefs': [
            {
               targets: 2, render: function(data1){ return moment(data1).format('dddd')},
            },
            {
               targets: -1, defaultContent: '<button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="Edit" type="button">Edit</button>'
                 + '&nbsp <button class="btn btn-danger" id="Delete" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Delete</button>'
            },
            { targets: 3, render: function(data2){ return moment(data2).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}},
        ]
    } );

   $('#calEvents').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
   //Unnecessary code
 });
```

Now i got only delete function, because i cant test if they working like one.

EDIT (add html code)
For datatable my html code is:

```
 <div class="row-90">
        <table class="table display" id="calEvents">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">GROUP</th>
                    <th scope="col">WEEKDAY</th>
                    <th scope="col">DATE</th>
                    <th scope="col">TICKER</th>
                    <th scope="col">EVENT</th>
                    <th scope="col">READX</th>
                    <th scope="col">ACTION</th>
               
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">GROUP</th>
                    <th scope="col">WEEKDAY</th>
                    <th scope="col">DATE</th>
                    <th scope="col">TICKER</th>
                    <th scope="col">EVENT</th>
                    <th scope="col">READX</th>
                    <th scope="col">ACTION</th>
        
                   
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need some how seperate them, i found solution how to do it. First need set button name, like this.

```
<button name="edit" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Edit</button>
```

then in js

```
 $('#calEvents').on( 'click', 'button[name="edit"]', function ()
```

and then working fine

Answer (score 0):

When setting the event handler, you're calling `$('#calEvents').on( 'click', 'button', function () {`. That will be applied for all the buttons. You'll need two separate functions and so event handlers.

Maybe ensure that `edit` and `delete` have different CSS classes, then you can use them in your jQuery selector in order to apply the two different event handlers.

Comment: with id cant use in my jQuery?

Comment: what I meant is to use both like this: `$('#calEvents .editButton').on` and `$('#calEvents .deleteButton').on`

Comment: i try, but its not working, maybe you can give me more information? like make button class editButton like this? `<button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" class="editButton" id="Edit" type="button">Edit</button>'` or something like what? because for now button not working right.

Comment: that could work, I'd need to see a bit more of your html to better understand the context.

Comment: i add html code for datatable. But idk or it helps.

Comment: So I expect your buttons to be part of tbody\tr\td and have CSS classes `editButton` and `deleteButton`. Then its enough to set the handlers like this: `$('#calEvents .editButton').click(function () { ...});` and `$('#calEvents .deleteButton').click(function () { ...});`. Now in the event handlers you'd still need to identify which row it will be acting upon.

Comment: you mean indentify json data rows? it will be a lot so i cant do what. In datatable i indentify row then i press on what row button. For now, then i use `$('#calEvents .editButton').click(function () ` button not working right. (They dont do anything). I just add that button in every my json data row. like u see in js code. it only use boostrap css.